# Publishing material on own website

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice, publishing

Im working on an open famous problem (i.e. a conjecture in mathematics), but i am having a hard time figuring out if i *can* or *should* publish any of the material im working on, on my website. I don't know if any of it is important for a future academic/scientific paper (I would want write). But if it is important, should I be more careful posting on my site?. Question is basically if something has allready been written and published on a website and it turned out to be an important result or proof of something, would it be accepted in a journal or **Arxiv** if it was allready published on a website?

Its not like I do advanced stuff, I do not have a phD or something, im amateur mathematician and love to do small puzzles and stuff. Would it turn out to be a problem if some of it was allready published on my website? And if someone else got ideas from my work, and decided to write a very mathematical paper about it without giving me the credit. Does this make it more obvious I should not post on my website, to keep it secret and hidden? Maybe the last bit is not something to be concerned about, but I still think its worth mentioning.

If I take it a little further, what if someone published a proof or some new material on say **math.stackexchange** (on this site), what would happen?

If this is a duplicate please refer me to the question.

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120346/what-is-the-best-way-for-an-amateur-mathematician-to-get-their-paper-reviewed?rq=1) is useful? Or, maybe, on the [Collatz-conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497833/where-is-the-flaw-in-this-proof-of-the-collatz-conjecture)?

Comment: It is a common practice for a faculty member to post his\her (journal or arxiv) papers in his\her personal web-page.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Im not claiming I have proof, as you probably can see. Anything related to this issue is useful. Though I got a pretty decent answer from Ethan Bolker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. nothing posted on your website would prevent you from posting on arXiv. Posting on arXiv would not usually prevent subsequently submitting to a refereed journal.

Longer answer. Your profile shows that you are really interested in the Collatz conjecture. I applaud your curiosity. That said, I think it unlikely that you will make real progress. As @DietrichBurde comments, you do not want to prejudice people's opinions of your possible eventual success by publishing (in any form) mistaken claims.

Your questions here seem to attract some positive attention, so I  suggest that you continue to ask them when you need help with intermediate results. If you or anyone else succeeds on Collatz with your methods that will establish some priority.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check out a journal such as the Mathematical Gazette? Perhaps access some of their articles (or articles of similar journals inclined towards the learning of mathematics) to see if your results would fit nicely there, and if so, format your paper accordingly and submit it. If the Editor finds no objections to it, he will then likely send it to a referee to review it. If it ultimately gets accepted, it will likely go through a series of revisions. If it doesn't get accepted, at least you will likely get some critical feedback that should help you in the future.

To look at a couple of recent articles, as well as the contents of some past issues, try this link:

https://www.m-a.org.uk/the-mathematical-gazette

Of course, if you have access to JSTOR, then you can review the contents of many journals (with a five year lag). Hope this helps.

Comment: Will check that out dude. (Mathematical Gazette).

Comment: When I try to get access to Mathematical Gazette Issues I get message: "You are not recognised as belonging to an institution.", why? I am not affiliated. No organization i know is in that list also.. hmmf